# How do I uninstall subversion on OS X

Tags: macos

I did svn --version on command line and it says it is 1.17.10.

I want to uninstall it completely, so I can re-install 1.16.12

How do I do that in OS X?

Thanks

Comment: Note that you don‘t need to uninstall 1.17 in order to install 1.16.

Comment: @EtienneMiret: How do I install 1.16 then? Please list the steps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As said Mike Christensen, in order to uninstall it, you just need to delete the binary. Run `which svn` to know where your binary is installed.

In order to install subversion, you need to:

1. [Download it](http://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/).
2. Uncompress it (`tar xzf subversion-1.x.y.tar.gz`).
3. Compile it (`./configure && make`).
4. Install it (`sudo make install`).

I’m pretty sure this will install it in /usr/local/bin. So if you want `svn` to call the subversion you just installed (instead of the one built in XCode), you need to edit your `$PATH` so that /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin. On Mac OS X, editing the path is done by editing the file /etc/paths.

Note that steps 3 and 4 requires a compiler and `make`. The easiest way to get those on Mac OS X is to install XCode.

Comment: Do you know what the `./configure` options are to install the `ra_neon` and `ra_serf` modules?

Comment: you forgot to mention that you should go into the tarred directory and then execute step 3.

Comment: I got the error `configure: error: failed to recognize APR_INT64_T_FMT on this platform` when executing step 3, and i followed instructions here (http://pablotips.blogspot.com/2013/12/install-svn-on-mac-os-x-again-this-time.html) to debug it successfully.

Comment: There was an error linking Xcode toolchain to get Command line tools, so I followed this before steps 3 & 4: (http://samoldak.com/updating-to-svn-1-8-for-mac-os-x-10-8/)

Comment: Also, svn wouldn't work with `http/https` if you don't have `serf` installed because I got this error `svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for`, so follow the link in the previous comment to install that as well, because especially the newer svn versions like 1.8 onwards only work with `serf`. Also look at (http://serverfault.com/questions/522646/svn-e170000-unrecognized-url-scheme-for-httpxxxx)

Comment: I ended up actually going down the `brew install svn` route and for that I had to first 1) uninstall all the existing files in `/usr/local/bin/` starting with `svn`. 2) Then I gave proper permissions to `/usr/local/` directory using `sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local` as described here (http://superuser.com/questions/254843/cant-install-brew-formulae-correctly-permission-denied-in-usr-local-lib). This way svn is installed in `/usr/local/bin/svn` and I verified the `svn --version` as `1.8.10`. HAPPY TIMES!

Comment: If you have a version of svn on it and you install another one with brew, in Yosemite that wont work.

Answer (score -1):

If you get any error in following Etienne Miret solution so the following
after setp 3

4. `brew install apr`
5. `brew install apr-util`
6. `/configure  --with-apr=/usr/local/Cellar/apr/1.5.2_3/ --with-apr-util=/usr/local/Cellar/apr-util/1.5.4_4 && make`
7. `sudo make install`

After completion, you can see the new SVN installed here

```
/usr/local/bin/svn --version
```