# SVN 1.6 - not a valid URL

Tags: macos, svn

Recently I uninstalled SVN 1.7 from mac osx and installed SVN 1.6.23 following the instructions on this page: [How do I uninstall subversion on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369274/how-do-i-uninstall-subversion-on-os-x)

'svn --version' runs well and says 1.6.23 is installed.

but when I run:

```
svn info http://www.domainname.com/svn/path_to_folder
```

it gives me following error:

```
http://www.domainname.com/svn/path_to_folder:  (Not a valid URL)
svn: A problem occurred; see other errors for details
```

The command works fine on another mac which had SVN 1.6.18 preinstalled. So there is no problem with the server or the commands. Does anyone know what it could be?

Comment: Does `svn --version` show any module that can speak `http`?

Comment: It shows ra_svn and ra_local modules only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any repository access module (RA) that can communicate with repositories using the HTTP protocol. If you only have `ra_svn` and `ra_local` you can only use `svn:` or `file:` URLs:

```
* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
```

You've apparently compiled your own binaries. The [INSTALL](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.6.23/INSTALL) file mentions this:

> b. Serf library 0.3.0 or newer (http://code.google.com/p/serf/)
>
> serf is a library for HTTP and WebDAV which is an   alternative to
>   Neon for accessing Subversion repositories    over http:// and https://
>   URLs.  serf is designed as an     asynchronous library which can take
>   advantage of HTTP     pipelining, so ra_serf may be more efficient than
>   ra_neon   and better for HTTP proxy caches.  The serf library can be
>     found at:
>
> ```
>  http://code.google.com/p/serf/
> ```
>
> In order to use ra_serf instead of ra_neon, you must install    serf,
>   and run Subversion's ./configure with the argument    --with-serf.  (To
>   only use ra_serf and not ra_neon, you     should also use
>   --without-neon.)  If serf is installed in a   non-standard place, you should use
>
> ```
>  --with-serf=/path/to/serf/install
> ```
>
> instead.  If you build with both ra_neon and ra_serf,   Subversion
>   will use ra_neon by default; add "http-library =  serf" to the
>   [global] section of your ~/.subversion/servers    file to use ra_serf
>   instead.
>
> For more information on serf and Subversion's ra_serf, see  the file
>   subversion/libsvn_ra_serf/README.