# Segmentation fault: 11 in SVN checkout

Tags: svn

I wanted to get project from code.google.com. I searched google and found that svn is shipped along with Mac OS. We just need to type the command in terminal. Here is the project.

```
$ svn checkout http://piccolo2d.googlecode.com/svn/piccolo2d.java/trunk piccolo2d.java
```

When i tired above command I got following issue. 
"Segmentation fault: 11"

I'm using OSX Yosemite.

Thank you for help

Comment: Please include the version of SVN that you are using.  You can find that by typing `svn help`.

Comment: Same problem with another project from code.google.com. I use svn 1.6.5 on Yosemite too

Comment: I'm using 1.6.5 that came with my OSX.. on Yosemite..

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112621/yosemite-svn-1-6-6-segmentation-fault/27123520#27123520

Comment: Hi imzcig, I'm a little new. I'm not able to run command..

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment. I hope you have find a workaround by now. If not, in the other question you can see how to compile the C sources of svn (actually svn + a few packages that are dependencies => become C libraries). I don't know much about C but was able to do it, however it's true it's a bit tricky. Anyhow, in my case I'm really stuck to svn 1.6 since the server in my company is in that version, we are not going to upgrade and it is not compatible with 1.7 client. But in your case I'd say you can use svn 1.7, which is available in Yosemite (1st you have to install xcode I believe).

Comment: I am also using 1.6.5 on Yosemite and have constantly the same error when i "svn checkout" something.

Comment: This also occurs on SVN 1.10.2 running on cygwin.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, getting rid of SVN 1.6.5 fixed it for me.

1. I figured out which SVN version I was on using `svn help` - turned out to be 1.6.5
2. I uninstalled SVN as outlined here - [How do I uninstall subversion on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369274/how-do-i-uninstall-subversion-on-os-x). (I went to /usr/local/bin and deleted all files starting with svn)
3. Everything works now. I'm now on SVN version 1.7.17. (I didn't install anything, I suspect this is related to me already having installed Xcode.)

Answer (score 0):

I you have [home brew](http://brew.sh/) then i found a simple solution...

1. brew install svn
2. Add an error linking so did: brew link --overwrite subversion
3. brew update svn

Comment: think this should be `brew upgrade svn` running update gives an error `This command updates brew itself, and does not take formula names.`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable isn't set to something invalid, as that can cause `svn` to segfault on every command.